# sql view refresh with period

Tags: sql, view, special-characters, period

I'm able to create a sqlview with peroid(.)

**create view [a.b] as select 1 as A**

but **sp_refreshview [a.b]** gives error:

*Msg 15165, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal, Line 55

Could not find object 'a.b' or you do not have permission.*

I tried **sp_refreshview 'a.b'**, no luck

How to do sp_refresh in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the view name in single quotes:  `sp_refreshview '[a.b]'`